# jQuery - Link to tabs outside of ul.tabs

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, hyperlink

How Could I change the script below so that clickable links to different tabs can be made outside of the `ul.tabs`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $tabContent = $(".tab-content"),
            $tabs = $("ul.tabs li"),
            tabId;

        $tabContent.hide();
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
        $tabContent.first().show();

        $tabs.click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $tabs.removeClass("active");
            $this.addClass("active");
            $tabContent.hide();
            var activeTab = $this.find("a").attr("href");
            $(activeTab).fadeIn();
            //return false;
        });

        // Grab the ID of the .tab-content that the hash is referring to
        tabId = $(window.location.hash).closest('.tab-content').attr('id');

        // Find the anchor element to "click", and click it
        $tabs.find('a[href=#' + tabId + ']').click();
    })

    $('a').not('.tabs li a').on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var whereTo = $(this).attr('goto');
        $tabs = $("ul.tabs li");
        $tabs.find('a[href=#' + whereTo + ']').trigger('click');
        //alert(attr('name'));
    //alert( $('#'+whereTo+' a').offset().top );
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#'+whereTo+' a').offset().top
        });

    });

    $(function() {
        $('a.refresh').live("click", function() {
            location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code from: http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/TGMDd/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already there for you, just specify the `goto` attribute which matches the `href` of the tab you want to go to:

```
<a href="#" goto="my_tab">Clicky</a>
```

will go to the tab set up as

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#my_tab">It goes here</a></li>
```

Comment: I beg to differ :) http://jsfiddle.net/TGMDd/7/ See the link right at the very top

Comment: nevermind, after a nights sleep I have it working after following your jsfiddle, many thanks Joe!

Comment: @Joe - is it possible to prevent from jumping to top of content? Also, what libraries need to be linked? I have it working in jsfiddle but not on my actual website. I only have jq 1.10.1 linked. THX!

Comment: @sloga You're better off asking a new question with all the details - I'm not quite sure what you're meaning with "jumping to the top of content" and without code to look at, I'd just be guessing